# Custom Claims and Checking for Pro Membership

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

With regards to [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client) in the context of Firebase Auth.

The following block is from the Firebase Docs:

```js
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
  .then((idTokenResult) => {
     // Confirm the user is an Admin.
     if (!!idTokenResult.claims.admin) {
       // Show admin UI.
       showAdminUI();
     } else {
       // Show regular user UI.
       showRegularUI();
     }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

If a Cloud Function is used to alter custom claims based on whether a user has paid for a membership, e.g. changing the custom claim for "pro_membership" to `true`; is it safe to check for this in the way above in a production app on the client side?
My main question really is: is there a way for a user to spoof this on the client side and change this value to true when they haven't subscribed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is client side code. So yes, it always possible to temper it. In the end one would simple need to flip the negation in your `if(...) else{...}` tree.

Everything in your react bundle will execute in an untrusted environment. The client environment. You have zero control over what happens there. The client could execute anything via the devtools console or have some browser extensions that do something like that.

For example, every adblocker extension is doing this. It simply removes calls/DOM nodes or JavaScript blocks that are meant for showing/executing ads.

Is it likely that people will create workarounds to access your premium app if you are not a big player in the industry? Not very likely. Is it security by obscurity? Yes it is.

If you really want such a feature, you need to gate it behind a backend that only sends out the premium UI JS and CSS bundles to the client, if the client really is a paying member. Aka doing the same admin claim check you are doing now in the frontend in a backend controller that can then decide to send it out or not.